# Error with code?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

Hi can anyone tell me why the following dose not work:

(p.s I dont want the file to append upon clicking abutton just upon clicking the checkbox.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\RXF\log.txt"

    'Adding items for AutoCAD 2006...
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine("module: 4FNV-67-5H")
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Explain "doesn't work" in more detail.

Comment: no error messages no problems, just the  file to be appended is not appending upon the checkbox being checked (checked if txt file exists and path is right, which is okay)

Comment: @tom: did you single-step through the code to verify that the condition in the `If` statement evaluates to `True`?

Comment: yeah hey that works but i put the true statement becuse i want to append the file and not overwrite it, which is whats happening now

Comment: just a sec seams to work now???

Comment: @Tom Like Fedrik says, put a debugger breakpoint in there to make sure the code is getting called. It's possible you haven't got the method hooked up to the event properly.

Answer (score -1):

**Not reproducible, even with your exact code as posted.** This works perfectly fine for me, creating a text file in the specified location if one does not exist and appending the specified text to the end of the file.

The only thing I suggest is wrapping your `StreamWriter` object in a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to ensure that its `Dispose` method always gets called, even if an exception is thrown (which is all the more likely when you're doing disk I/O). So, your existing code would simply change to:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\RXF\log.txt"

    ''#Adding items for AutoCAD 2006...
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Using objWriter as New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
            objWriter.WriteLine("module: 4FNV-67-5H")
            objWriter.Close()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, if you anticipate this method getting called a lot (i.e., the user clicking and unclicking and clicking the checkbox repeatedly), you might consider creating the `StreamWriter` object *once* and saving it as a private class-level variable, instead of creating and disposing of it each time the method is called. Then you just have to make sure that you dispose of it whenever your class (presumably the containing form) is disposed.